# Draw Straight Line in EditText (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any way, we could add (draw) straight horizontal line in EditTexts below:

```
<EditText 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/Text1" 
/>
 <EditText 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@+id/Text2" 
 />
```

I am trying to put the line just where text (in EditText) appears in the box, just above the Box.

Thank you.

Comment: Inside the EditTexts or above the EditTexts? Or between them?

Comment: inside editText. However, this would have text inside it, but the straight line should be just above the text, like crossing those texts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Paint flag:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text1);
et.setPaintFlags(someTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: Thank you. But, its showing Rendering Problems as below:
Exception raised during rendering: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

May be I am missing something.

Below is the xml I have used:
<EditText 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/Text1">
<View 
 android:id="@+id/line" 
 android:background="#000000" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="10px"/>
<EditText/>

Thank you.

Comment: @Pikey What kind of rendering problems is it having?

Comment: Hi Arjun, I accidently hit Enter. Please check above.

Comment: @Pikey see my edit with the full page (within RelativeLayout or whatever you are using)

Comment: Hi Arjun, thanks a lot. The code above creates a line, but not above the EditText box, which I am trying to do. View element needs to be inside EditText, and that straight should be just in the middle of the EditText box.

Thank you.

Comment: @Pikey So you want an edittext with text, and a line just above the text? Like underlining but above?

Comment: Hi Arjun. I want an EditText where I could put some text, and I would like to cross those text inside the EditText with that straight line, while text still in the EditText.
Thanks.

Comment: @Pikey what you mean by cross? Is the line through the text, between the two EditTexts, or above each EditText separately?

Comment: Hi Arjun, its line through the text above each EditText separately. We could ignore the second EditText for the time being. Thanks.

Comment: @Pikey Do you mean that the text is struck through, like this: T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶u̶c̶k̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶ ?

Comment: Hi Arjun. Yes, I wanted this.

Comment: Hi arjun, 
Thanks, I got it from setPaintFlags. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Pikey That's the same thing I found. Mark the answer as correct so anyone who sees the question can find the answer.